# Convert IEnumerable to IEnumerable<T> when T isn't known until runtime

Tags: .net, generics, reflection

How can I convert `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<T>` when T isn't known until runtime?

I have a method that **absolutely needs an `IEnumerable<T>` where T isn't known until runtime** and **`T` must be the actual type and not an ancestor type like object**.

I'm betting the reflection API allows for something like this but I don't know exactly how.

### Update

I can get a type object like this:

```
var first = results.Cast<object>().FirstOrDefault();
if (first != null)
{
    var type = first.GetType();

}
```

### Update2

The "method" I was referring to was actually the Setter of the WPF DataGrid's ItemSource property.
The problem I'm having is that if I don't pass it an `IEnumerable<T>` the rows generated in the Datagrid are all blank, as if it's method of reflecting over the properties of `T` is not working and it can't generate columns.

Even using this code has this unwanted effect:

```
    public CollectionResultWindow(IEnumerable results)
    {
        Contract.Requires(results != null, "results is null.");

        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        var first = results.Cast<object>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (first != null)
        {
            Type type = first.GetType();
            var castMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(type);
            dynamic genericResults = castMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { results });
            Results = genericResults; // Results is a dependency property that DataGrid.ItemSource is bound to.
        }

    }
```

Comment: How do you know the type of `T` at runtime? Do you have a `Type` object?

Comment: @Daniel - Yes I have a T object at runtime. See my update.

Comment: @Daniel - I don't know T at runtime. The computer has a Type object at runtime.

Comment: where from results comming in? basically who adding an elements to results collection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var elementType = ...
var results = ...
var castMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(elementType);
var genericResults = castMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { results });
```

The `genericResults` variable refers to an object of type `IEnumerable<T>` (where `T` is the type represented by the `elementType` variable). But keep in mind that statically, `genericResults` is still of type `object`; there is no way to tell the compiler that it is an `IEnumerable<T>`, since `T` isn't known statically.

Comment: Your last sentence states why your answer isn't going to help him. He can't pass `genericResults` to his method.

Comment: @Ronnie: See my answer. It should fix this.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, in that case the method he needs to call is probably generic too... So if the generic type argument isn't known until runtime it should also be called using reflection.

Comment: See my update which is much more transparent about why I'm trying to do. @ Thomas - I am on .net 4

Comment: @Ronnie, if you want to assign it to an ItemsSource, just cast the result of `Invoke` to `IEnumerable` (`IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that worked for me:

```
    public CollectionResultWindow(IEnumerable results)
    {
        Contract.Requires(results != null, "results is null.");

        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        var first = results.Cast<object>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (first != null)
        {
            Type type = first.GetType();
            var castMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList").MakeGenericMethod(type);
            dynamic genericResults = castMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { results });
            Results = genericResults; // Results is a dependency property that DataGrid.ItemSource is bound to.
        }

    }
```