# Convert IEnumerable<A> to IEnumerable<B> without knowing types at compile time

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have two types: let's call them A and B.  A can be converted to B using an adapter method.

I then have a collection of A's in a `List<A>` (it could be any collection type that supports `IEnumerable<A>`).

I now want to convert from `IEnumerable<A>` to `IEnumerable<B>`.  I know the `Type` of each of A and B, and I have a method to convert an A into a B, but my method and/or class is not templated itself, so I do not have access to the template type; e.g. the T in `IEnumerable<T>`.

I effectively want to write this ConvertCollection method, where I know "from" is of type `IEnumerable<{something}>`:

```
object ConvertCollection(object from, Type fromType, Type toType, Converter converter);
```

My converter looks like this:

```
delegate object Converter(object from);
```

My attempt leaves me here:

```
object ConvertCollection(object from, Type fromType, Type toType, Converter converter)
{
    return ((IEnumerable<object>)from).Select(converter);
}
```

which partly works.  If I call it like this

```
ConvertCollection(new List<A>() { new A() }, typeof(A), typeof(B), AToBConverter);
```

the returned collection does contain a collection of Bs, but the collection itself is of type `IEnumerable<object>`, not `IEnumerable<B>`, because I don't know how to cast to `IEnumerable<{toType}>`.  (It matters because the result needs to be serialized).

I can attack it from the other end and create the correct return type like this:

```
var result = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(toType));
// TODO: populate result here
return result;
```

but then the problem is that to achieve the TODO part, I need to call List<> methods on result, but I can't cast it to any type of `List<>` because of Co/ContraVariance rules, so even though I know the type supports `List<>` methods, I can't get at them to use them to populate the list; e.g. to use Add().

Is there a way to do this without using 'dynamic' and without too much reflection?  I know I could locate and invoke the Add() method via reflection, but it seems like it shouldn't be necessary.

.NET 4.0 BTW

**-- Clarification**

As Euphoric correctly speculates, and I tried but rather badly failed to convey above, I know the types A and B at runtime, but I do not know them at compile time.  Hence the direct use of generics is not an option.  I do know that the collections (both supplied and as must be returned) implement the generic `IEnumerable<>`.  That is all fixed and outside my control.  (I've adjusted the title accordingly).

** Edit 2: fixed some formatting causing `<>` to not display (easy to accidentally omit the back-ticks!)

Comment: If you have an adapter method that transforms an `A` into a `B`, can you not use something like `IEnumerable<A>.Select(a => AdapterMethodThatReturnsB(a))` to get an `IEnumerable<B>`? Is the problem that this should work for any arbitrary types, assuming the existence of a conversion function?

Comment: @DanJ - I guess the issue is that the OP is passing in `object` and returning `object` instead of using the _actual_ types (or generics, for that matter).

Comment: By saying you know Type, you are saying you know it at compile time or at runtime? Because generics are meant to make programming easier by doing strong typing at compile time. If you don't know types beforehand, just use non-generic IEnumerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I settled on was to use reflection to invoke the `Enumerable.Cast<>` method to cast the resultant collection from `IEnumerable<object>` to the correct `IEnumerable<>` type.  I got the idea from the answer to this question: [Convert IEnumerable to IEnumerable<T> when T isn't known until runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108759/convert-ienumerable-to-ienumerablet-when-t-isnt-known-until-runtime).  Seems to involve very little performance penalty.

So the full answer becomes:

```
object ConvertCollection(object from, Type fromType, Type toType, Converter converter)
{
    var partialResult = ((IEnumerable<object>)from).Select(converter);
    var castMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(toType);
    return castMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { partialResult });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. I combined it with a subsequent similar  call to `ToList` and it works miracles ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Using the LINQ `Select` method:

```
var result = listA.Select(a => Converter(a));
```

Since you are using .NET 4.0, you really should avoid using `object` and use generics.

Comment: This is basically as I had it above, is it not?  The problem is that because the return type of Converter is object, result becomes a collection of objects, rather than a collection of B's, even though it contains B's.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
IEnumerable<TTo> ConvertCollection<TFrom,TTo>(object from, Converter converter)
{
    return ((IEnumerable<TFrom>)from).Select(a=>(TTo)converter(a)).ToList();
}
```

Then you simply call it:

```
ConvertCollection<A,B>(new List<A>() { new A() }, AToBConverter);
```

Comment: That would work if I knew the types at compile time, but as you suggested elsewhere, I don't.  Apologies for the initial vagueness; my bad.